# How to change the order of realtime database firebase data in Descending order?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a quiz app with questions in each set. When set 1 is clicked questions are loaded in that set. I want to load the recently added questions before the previous ones.

As default, the latest question goes down the list. Help me out.

```
database.getReference().child("Sets").child(categoryName).child("questions")
.orderByChild("setNum").equalTo(set)
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.exists()){

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){

                QuestionModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(QuestionModel.class);
                list.add(model);
            }

            if (list.size()>0){


                for (int i=0;i<4;i++){

                    binding.optionContainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            checkAnsw((Button)view);

                        }
                    });
                }
```

[image: Database]

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database always orders nodes in **ascending** order. It has no operation to put then in descending order. --- This means you will have to reverse the order of the items in the client, either in the application code (e.g. `list.add(0, model)`), or in the UI. An alternative would be to store an inverted value in the database and order on that, but I don't recommend that here. --- I've linked some prevoius questions about this topic.